# Buttons and Errors

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to programming and I wanted to make three buttons that add `X+1`, `X+3` and `X+5` respectively.  I tried something and the error "BC30491" pops up. Here's the code (Don't mind the Do (25) and the loop(27))

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Panel1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Campis1.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Campis2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Campis2.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Añ1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Añ1.Click
    Do
        Añ1_Click(sender, e).PerformClick = TextBox1.Text = "1"

    Loop


End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What is the error stack trace and message?  What did you try which made the error pop up?

Comment: You cannot assign anything to a method which is what `PerformClick` is, Read [ask] and take the [tour].  We do not need 5 empty event handlers to understand the problem...they are empty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
Añ1_Click(sender, e).PerformClick = TextBox1.Text = "1"
```

With:

```
TextBox1.Text = "1"
```

And remove the `Do` loop.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I alredy tryed to do it and it didn't work

Comment: Can you describe "didn't work"? Same error? New error? Error on different line? I'm free this evening and I don't mind walking through this with you for a few hours if needed, but you're going to have to provide much more detail.

Comment: That "didnt work" means that I done that after the code I posted and the same error occurred

Comment: Understood. One crazy question - does TextBox1 exist? I see you have a TextBox2 there but I don't see a reference to TextBox1. A common mistake I used to make is people renaming the form element and forgetting to change the references to it. So TextBox1 still exists and has same name? (Also if you want to post the whole project somewhere I don't mind downloading it and tinkering around to see if I can fix. Totally optional though)

Comment: IM SO DUMB, I dont know why I was thinking that TextBox1 was the "only one" that I created, but hey! that common mistake keeps happening, thank you for your time hahaha

Comment: Done! And if you want to help me more, the thing im making is a dumb idea but I wanted to do it because is easy for me use this than a paper and a pen hehe